# On the structure of generators an endomorphism ring over an infinite dimensional vector space.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, abelian-groups, abelian-categories

Let $D$ be a division ring, $V$ a right $D$-vector space of infinite dimension. Write $R=End(V_D)$. I'm trying to prove the following:

> $R$ is a minimal generators over $R$-$\mathsf{Mod}$, that is, for any generator  $M$ in $R$-$\mathsf{Mod}$ (that is, for any $R$-module $N$, there is an epimorphism from $M^{(I)}$ to $N$), there is an epimorphism from $M$ onto $R$.

Can anyone give me some ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean that, for every non-zero $R$-module $M$ there is an epi from $M$ to $R$?

Comment: @HanulJeon No, I mean for every generator $M$ there is an epi from $M$ to $R$.